# firefox 3 favicons - how to make them?

Tags: html, firefox, favicon

i noticed that paypal displays a very different favicon,
one that's not just a simple 16x16 icon and is lengthy?
anyone can teach me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are refering to the green box that shows the PayPal logo followed by "PayPal, Inc. (US)".

If so, it is not a favicon, but a feature of Firefox 3 to show sites with extended validation (EV). See also http://news.cnet.com/8301-13554_3-9974672-33.html

Answer (score 5):

That is not a favicon, but the type of SSL certificate they use.  It's an [Extended Validation (EV)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate) certificate, which intends to provide better identity verification.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy.  Under the {title} tag, you put this code.

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
```

Just make sure that the favicon image is less than 100px * 100px. My recommended favicon image size is 50px * 50px.